# How to get legend labels that differ from fill aesthetic in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `ggplot2`, how do I get the legend labels for the fill aesthetic to differ from the variable actually used as the fill aesthetic? What I'd like to see from the following plot is the legend labels reflecting the `name` variable. I know I could just use the `name` itself as the fill aesthetic; however, in the following example, it's more convenient to set up the colour vector `storm_cols` (used for `ggplot2::scale_fill_manual`) using the `id` column as the vector names rather than typing out each `name`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat <-
    storms %>% 
    filter(year >= 2015) %>% 
    group_by(name, year) %>% 
    summarize(avg_wind = mean(wind)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(id = as.character(row_number())) %>% 
    slice(1:4)
storm_cols <- c("1" = "red", "2" = "blue", "3" = "green", "4" = "yellow")
dat %>% 
    ggplot(aes(id, avg_wind, fill = id)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = storm_cols)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `override.aes` ... search on SO or elsewhere and see what you come up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly type out the names for the color vector. Instead, you can create it programmatically, making it easier to create the desired color assignments and use `name` directly as the fill aesthetic. For example, in this case you can use the `set_names` function from the `purrr` package (or the base R `setNames` function).

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(id, avg_wind, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","blue","green","yellow") %>% set_names(dat$name))
```

[image]

With your original example, you could change the legend labels with the `labels` argument to `scale_fill_manual`:

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(id, avg_wind, fill = id)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = storm_cols,
                    labels = dat$name)
```